# Are nesting exceptions allowed on *x86 systems*?

Tags: exception, x86

In my uni course we learned that nested interrupts can occur, but NOT nested exceptions (software interrupts), **except for page faults**. i.e. when getting an exception from an exception handler, we will never return to executing the old exception handler.

I've read on [IBM's site](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/i/7.3?topic=program-handling-nested-exceptions) that this is, in fact, possible, but I guess it's only true for their systems, and not necessarily x86 systems.

Also, if it's true, then double and triple faults never return to execute the handlers that invoked them?

Comment: A triple fault causes a processor shutdown, there's no fault handler for it. A double fault handler can theoretically return, but in practice it doesn't make sense because the fault isn't recoverable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On 80x86; all exceptions can be nested as deep as you like.

The only restriction are exceptions that are caused when trying to start an exception handler.

For example; if the CPU tries to start a page fault handler but can't because it triggers a second page fault; then you get a double fault instead. However; if the CPU successfully starts the page fault handler then the page fault handler's code can happily be interrupted by a second page fault.

Note that "can be nested" does not mean an OS does support it; and there's a few options (the IST mechanism in long mode, the TSS gate mechanism in protected mode) that, if used by the OS, prevent the OS from supporting nesting. Also; if nesting is supported by the OS there's often a limit to stack size (e.g. you might nest 10 times and then cause a stack overflow).

Comment: Just to be clear, when the handler code is happily interrupted by a second exception - will we go back to executing the old handler when we're done with the new one? Note that I've asked about exceptions that are not page faults (since we've been told that page faults *can* be nested)

Comment: @Suspicious_1: Yes, when the inner exception handler returns you go back to the next outer exception handler and it can continue without problems It's the same for all exceptions, including double fault (where you can return in theory but its unlikely to make sense in practice).